# Argparse throws invalid syntax error despite valid code

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I made a working code to perform a function and the output is as intended to be. I tried to convert this code to use argparse to process in command line, (`Using Spyder, MacOS`) but keep getting :Syntax Error

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Read file with header only to create emptyDataframe and populate with map entries')
    parser.add_argument('file1', type=str, help='File to map')
    parser.add_argument('file2', type=str, help='File to search')
    parser.add_argument('output', type=str, help='dataframe output')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Perform operations on input files and save the result to the output file
    process_files(args.file1, args.file2, args.output)

def process_files(file1, file2, output):
    # Your code to process the input files and save the result to the output file
    df = pd.read_csv(file1, delim_whitespace=True, header=0, index_col=0)

    with open(file2, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            elements = line.strip().split(" ")
            first_element = elements.pop(0)
            df.loc[first_element] = 'NaN'   
            for each in elements:
                if each in df.columns:
                    df.at[first_element, each] = each  # Match found, assign to corresponding column
                else:
                    pass # Match not found, assign NA

    print("Final dataframe...")
    print(df)
    df.to_csv(output, sep="\t")
    print("DataFrame saved to", output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Execution in command-line gives

```
python3 populate_df_shellv.py to_map.txt to_search.txt populated_dataframe_shell.tsv
  Cell In[20], line 1
    python3 populate_df_shellv.py to_map.txt to_search.txt populated_dataframe_shell.tsv
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the issue? Please help.

Comment: What's this `cell In[20], line 1`?  That doesn't look like a OS shell line (windows or bash,  etc).  This isn't an 'argparse' error.

Comment: I think you are trying to run the code from a jupyter notebook, not from the command line. If you are using windows, you start the command line by hitting start -> type "cmd" -> hit return. With cd "path\to\this\directory" you change the current directory to the one where your script lives. Then you try again to execute your script.

Comment: I am using sypder in MacOS

Comment: you are right. When I run in terminal, there is no error displayed.